# Laravel 5.8 no longer connects to AWS RDS with environment variables

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have a Laravel project running on AWS with environment vars stored in Elastic Beanstalk. It has been working with the same DB username and password for a couple of years, but upon updating to Laravel 5.8 the database connection ceased. I CAN still connect to mysql using this username and password from my laptop, but the EC2 instance (created by Elastic Beanstalk) won't connect.

So far:
I quickly found this in the Laravel docs : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#environment-variable-parsing

> the # character in an unquoted value will now be considered a comment instead of part of the value.
> To preserve the previous behaviour, you may wrap the environment values in quotes:

```
ENV_VALUE="foo#bar"

env('ENV_VALUE'); // foo#bar
```

And my password DID contain a #! So I thought that was it. AWS environment vars removes double quotes, so that solution is not possible. I changed the DB users password to one without a hash - same result. The error log from Laravel is just giving me :

```
[2020-07-25 20:55:31] testing.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myusername'@'1xx.x.x.x' (using password: YES) (SQL: insert into `mytable` (`field`, `field2`,[stacktrace]
```

Comment: Does changing to a simple alphanumeric password work?

Comment: What do you mean that "AWS environment vars removes double quotes"? If you want quotes with your env variables set using EB, you can escape them, e.g. `\"foo#bar\"`.

Comment: Thanks. So its not the double quotes. Even with the escaped quotes \" its not accepted that password. So strange that I can log in with that password using SequelPro but the app won't allow access to it...

Comment: @ChrisWilliams changed to a simple alphanumeric password - still Access Denied

Comment: Have you checked you can login with exact credentials you are using in your env variables (if you echo out the values)?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I can, yes. I can copy the username and password from ELB vars to Sequel Pro and log in. I can also connect to the DB using ELB if I use the root username and password. But I CAN'T connect from ELB to the RDS DB using any other username and password, and that started happening the moment I deployed my Laravel 5.8 update